# How to divide two buttons into two halves of the layout?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I know that the question is quite badly asked. But all I want to know is how to do the thing shown in picture below also with the small white border between them
in android layout? Can anybody help me?

[two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CMrv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using a LinearLayout and  `layout_weight` parameter, you can do it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2.0"
    style="?attr/buttonBarStyle">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:text="Button One"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button Two"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The style is to make it look good in a bar without much effort.

Comment: `weightSum` is completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do it using `layout_weight` (like below code) or you can use `gridlayout`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

<ImageView  
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Inside a `RelativeLayout` create the first `Button` and then a `LinearLayout` with height the same as the `RelativeLayout` and width 2dp and with the attribute `android:background="#fff"` and with ex `android:layout_toRightOf:"@+id:button_1"` and then create the second button with attribute ex `android:layout_toRightOf:"@+id:linear_layout1"`